# Overlap iterables with given n and m without len() use

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

I am trying to make an overlap function in python that takes any iterable, an int *n*, and an int *m* (whose default value is 1) as parameters, and produce lists of *n* values:

1. The first list contains the first *n* values;
2. Every subsequent list drops the first *m* from the previous list
3. Adds next *m* values from the iterator, until there are fewer than *n* values to put in the returned list.

**Example:**

```
for i in overlap('abcdefghijk',4,2):
    print(i,end=' ')
```

Its output is `['a','b','c','d']`, `['c','d','e','f']`, `['e','f','g','h']`, and `['g','h',i','j']` for `n=4` and `m=2`. In this case if the function is something like this:

```
def overlap(iterable, n, m=1)
```

How can this be done? The main problem I am facing is how to stop when there are less than *n* values.

Current code: credits to [anmol_uppal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29896919/2943635).

```
def hide(iterable):
    for v in iterable:
        yield v

def overlap(word, n, m):
    start = 0
    while(start+n < len(word)):
        yield list(word[start:start+n])
        start += m

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    for i in overlap('abcdefghijk',3,2): 
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
    for i in overlap(hide('abcdefghijk'),3,2): 
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
```

But the problem is we cannot use `len()` with generators.

I have tried this code but I don't know why it's giving unexpected results for the second test case

```
def hide(iterable):
    for v in iterable:
        yield v

def window(seq, size, step=1):
    iters = [iter(seq) for i in range(size)]
    [next(iters[i]) for j in range(size) for i in range(-1, -j-1, -1)]
    while(True):
        yield [next(i) for i in iters]
        [next(i) for i in iters for j in range(step-1)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in window('abcdefghijk', 3, 2): 
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
    for i in window(hide('abcdefghijk'), 3, 2): 
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please check the problem now. Its not duplicate

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski Please remove duplicate tag as problem is not duplicate

Comment: Why are you using `hide()` its doing nothing special?

Comment: @anmol_uppal I need to use it . I cant change or modify hide function. But need to modify my overlap function. It ensures code works on general iterable parameters (not just a string, tuple, list, etc.)

Comment: @anmol_uppal  Are you getting the point of using it now ?

Comment: It still doesn't makes sense to me sorry for that , but I fixed the code, and now it works for strings at least

Comment: @anmol_uppal I dont want it for string only. That is main role of hide()

Answer (score 1):

```
def overlap(word, n,m):
    ans = []
    start = 0
    while(start+n<len(word)):
        ans.append(list(word[start:start+n]))
        start+=m

    return ans


>>> print overlap("abcdefghijk", 4, 2)
>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
>>> print overlap("abcdefghi", 4, 2)
>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Also if you would like to yield the results instead of returning them,then you can use the following simpler version:

```
def overlap(word, n,m):
    start = 0
    while(start+n<len(word)):
        yield list(word[start:start+n])
        start+=m

for i in overlap("abcdefghijk", 4, 2):
    print (i,end = " ")
```

To make it work with the `hide()` function you need to convert it to string first, so:

```
for i in overlap("".join(hide("abcdefghijk")),3, 2): 
    print i
```

Comment: I need to yield the result so that i can do for i in overlap('abcdefghijk',4,2):
        print(i,end=' ')

Comment: Are you getting it ?

Comment: Yeah I am going to edit the answer, see it it suits you.

Comment: Mark it with a Green tick if this helped you, Thanks.

Comment: Getting runtime error http://ideone.com/ksb4P3

Comment: You cant use len like this

Comment: First please help to resolve the problem. I will surely mark it green..:)

Comment: Sorry but your question was regarding the overlapping of iterables which is being solved, Another error of which you are talking about is due to the `hide()` function written by you , and I hold no responsibility of errors caused by your scripts, My script is working fine and generating the correct output.

Comment: Let me edit it in post then

Comment: I want to avoid len(). Please suggest a way out for it

Comment: This is the most I can do, Sorry if it doesn't satisfies you.